# How to handle multiple users with Sqlite3+python?

Tags: python, sqlite, database-connection

I am creating simple webapp, several users(~5-10max) will be adding data frequently(Say every 2-5 minutes). Webapp is powered by Flask and database is sqlite3. How can I make sure that when someone has "Open connection" to database, other's request will "queue" or "wait". Similarly is it possible, to read data while someone else is modifying it.(In READ-ONLY mode)

Should I just warn and restrict users? That'll make things a lot less complicated.

P.S. - For some reasons I can't use client-server configuration. DB size will never go more than ~200MB

Comment: So you can't use another database, e.g. Postgres?

Comment: @mhawke as I said, I can't use any client-server based SQL solutions. Postgre is server based AFAIK.

Comment: SQLite handles concurrent access just fine, if you give each client their own connection and you use transactions properly.